# Facing difficulty using compound query with Elasticsearch JS

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

I am using the official Elasticsearch package from npm within my node.js application. I was attempting to perform search using compound queries ( bool), But I found that the compound search does not work as expected.

To debug the issue, I tried passing different sets of data for the search query. I found an abnormality wherein the elasticsearch library does not work as expected but the Elasticsearch API does. I'm unable to find this behavior documented anywhere else as well.

I executed 2 sets of code (with the same query) on
1) Node using the official elastic search library
2) Over the Elasticsearch API using Postman

I> Using Elastic Search JS

```
    "index": "bank",
    "type": "account",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "address": "avenue"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

II> Using Elastic Search API

```
    "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "address": "avenue"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
}
```

The results for the official library come in empty (Empty array), But the results using the elasticsearch API result in the correct set of data.

Another peculiar observation was the below query using elasticsearch JS which works for a single element, but not an array of elements

```
    "index": "bank",
    "type": "account",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match": {
                        "address": "avenue"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm breaking my head over where I'm going wrong, I tried going through docs, stackoverflow and a very little bit of code, And returned empty handed.

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot